# PyQt4 QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt

[Python Version: 3.7.7, Windows 10, MySQL 8, PyQt version: 4.11.4]

I've checked everywhere and found no solution to my situation. This is the error I get in the console

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QPSQL7 QPSQL QODBC3 QODBC QSQLITE
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

And this is my code

```
def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
    db.setHostName('localhost')
    db.setDatabaseName('shopping')
    db.setPassword('mce')
    db.open()
    print(db.lastError().text())
    return True
```

I've checked the directory C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins and I don't even have a sqldrivers folder so they must stored somewhere else (if they even truly exist). I've reinstall the MySQL python connector and I still have the same problem. I've also made a sqldrivers folder in C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins and put libmysql.dll in there, just to see if it would work and obviously it didn't.

Comment: After realising PyQt5 is not that different from PyQt4, I'm switching. It's not worth the headache anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to PyQt5 only to find the very same problem there. So after spending days on this problem, the best solution is to just download the drivers.
Follow this [link](https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases/tag/qmysql_5.15.1_mysql8)

I can confirm that these files work on PyQt5 but they should also work on PyQt4. I used the qsqlmysql.dll and the qsqlmysqld.dll files and put them in C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers. Everything was detected